# Why iOS 10 Calendar.current.timeZone not return my local timezone?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

In iOS 10, `Calendar.current.timeZone` returns `GMT`. While in iOS 11, `Calendar.current.timeZone` returns my local timezone, which is correct.

Is that a bug in iOS 10? How to workaround it?

Comment: I'm not aware of this bug, but have you tried `TimeZone.current`?

Comment: @Gonzo It's the same.

Comment: That's interesting.. Don't know how to solve :( Are you trying on a device or simulator?

Comment: It's on a simulator. I will find an iOS 10 device to test it. Update the post later.

Comment: I got the same issue here, iOS 11 correct tz, iOS 10 GMT

Comment: tested on iPhone?

Comment: No, it was on simulator. But now I got a device (iPhone 5), running iOS 10.3.3 (the same version of the simulator) and now it worked fine.

Comment: Apparently more people noticed this issue https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/18561

Comment: Thanks for the link. Exactly the same testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar.timezone returns the UTC. You need to convert UTC into Eastern time or your specific timezone.

https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-edt-converter

Comment: I'm betting the OP already knows how to get local time from UTC time; the OP is asking why the conversion is needed for iOS 10;  also, an on-line converter is not going to help inside of the application the OP is writing